# Listar arquivos em uma pasta que contenham uma palavra especifica no nome

Tags: php, lista, joomla, sistema-de-arquivos

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em [Joomla!](https://www.joomla.org/) e preciso disponibilizar arquivos específicos para cada um usuário (holerite). Já consegui por meio da sessão saber qual usuário está logado. No Joomla!, fiz uma inclusão de um campo a mais no banco de dados para inserir um número de cadastro do usuário, esse número é o que diferencia os nomes dos arquivos de holerite, gostaria de fazer no php uma página que listasse os arquivos dentro de um diretório que contenham o número do cadastro específico do usuário.

Ex.: Um dos arquivos tem esse formato

```
holerith 000956  Dezembro de 2016.pdf
holerith 000957  Dezembro de 2016.pdf
```

Ao logar o usuário 1, o código dele é 000956 que eu já consegui pegar pela sessão. Gostaria então de exibir somente o arquivo correspondente dele, para cada usuário somente ver o seu holerite. Alguém tem alguma ideia de como posso fazer isso no PHP?

Aliás esse é o código que usei no PHP para pegar na sessão do Joomla qual usuário está logado.

```
<?php
// Recuperando Sessão do usuário Joomla
define('_JEXEC', 1);
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
$path = "\\xampp\htdocs\TESTES\Joomla_Teste";  //caminho da instalação do Joomla
define('JPATH_BASE', $path);
require_once JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'defines.php';
require_once JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'framework.php';

$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$db = &JFactory::getDBO();
$mainframe->initialise();
$user =& JFactory::getUser( );


echo $user->id;  //imprime id do usuário
echo $user->name; //imprime nome do usuário
echo $user->password; // Imprime senha do usuário
echo $user->cod_func; // imprime o código do usuário

?>
```

Answer (score 4):

O ideal seria testar com preg_match se o arquivo contém o que tu precisa.
Percorre os arquivos e com a string do nome de cada um, faz algo do gênero.

```
<?php
$encontrou = preg_match("/(?:holerith)(?:.+?)(?<codigo_usuario>\d+)/", $string_com_arquivo, $output_array);
?>
```

No $output_array, terá um índice codigo_usuario, compara com o que tu tem e feito ;)

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/bpyV2O/1

Answer (score 1):

Para listar arquivos em uma ou mais pastas você pode usar [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

```
// codigo do usuário
$codigo = '1234';
// arquivos .pdf na pasta /path/ começados com holerith com 1234 no nome.
$arquivos = glob('/path/holerith*'.$codigo.'*.pdf');
```

Isso posto, talvez você esteja resolvendo o problema pelo lado mais difícil desnecessariamente. Essa solução depende de você excluir do diretório os arquivos que não estão mais disponíveis e isso é um complicador.

Normalmente quando existe um volume variável de arquivos para baixar por usuário o procedimento comum é registrar no banco quais desses arquivos estão disponíveis e apresentar essa lista pro usuário sem precisar ler do sistema.

Isso reduz o consumo de recursos já que você não precisa ler o `filesystem` toda vez que um usuário carregar a página. Se precisar de confirmação de que o arquivo existe pode iterar pela lista guardada no banco e conferir cada arquivo com [`file_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-exists.php). Considere se essa ideia não resolve melhor o seu problema.

Comment: Realmente o ideal seria colocar essas informações direto no banco de dados mais, no caso desse sistema que vou desenvolver é um sistema de holerite todo mês o arquivo vai mudar ou acrescentar um novo e são mais de 400 usuários, seria trabalhoso efetuar o upload de cada arquivo informando qual usuário correspondente, pois quem vai fazer isso é o RH. O que eu queria mesmo era, colocar todo mês os arquivos de holerite um uma pasta (pode ficar varias meses desde que seja do mesmo usuário) e no php eu exiba esse diretório para download mas filtrando pelo usuário. Meu conhecimento Php é baixo

Comment: Nesse caso essa solução te resolve. Só achei por bem colocar o aviso pra quem mais estiver procurando.

Answer (score 0):

Fiquei pensando no havia me dito sobre recursos então resolvi mudar meu código para algo mais simples e ficou assim, ainda não esta finalizado mas já da para ter uma ideia de como vai ficar

```
<?php
 function varSet($VAR) { return isset($_GET[$VAR]) ? $_GET[$VAR] : ""; }
 $action = varSet("action");
 $pasta = base64_decode(varSet('pasta'));

 //Lista dos arquivos que nao serão listados
 $denyFiles = array(".htaccess","thumbs.db");

 if ($action == "download") {
    $file = base64_decode(varSet("file"));
        header("Content-disposition: attachment; 
        filename=\"".basename($file)."\"");
        readfile(".$file");
    exit;
 }
?>

<?php
 $pasta = '/arquivos';
 $arquivos = "$user->cod_func".'  Outubro de 2016.pdf';
 $filename = 'arquivos/'.$arquivos;
 if (file_exists($filename)) {
?>
<a href="?action=download&file=<?php echo base64_encode("$pasta/$arquivos"); ?>"><?php echo $arquivos; ?></a>
<br>
<?php
} else {
 echo "Não existe holerith no mês selecionado";
}
?>
```